# C# Placeholders in Exceptions

Tags: c#, custom-exceptions

Stupid question but I really can't find the answer of it. 
How can you insert a place holder in the the exceptions like this?
And is it even possible?

```
  public int Age
{
    get
    {
        return this.age;
    }
    set
    {
        this.age = value;
        if((0 >= value) || (value > 100))
        {


            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The age {0}  you've entered must be in the range [1..100]",value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of placeholder are you looking for?

Comment: to show the value of the age check the exception again i edited it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `string.Format` with {0}, {1}...etc. placeholders:

```
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format(
    "The age {0} you've entered must be in the range [1..100]", 
    value));
```

Answer (score 0):

As `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` expecting a string, you can't pass placeholder to it directly. To construct a string with placeholder you should use `string.Format()` method. Which gives the formatted string.

```
string message = string.Format("The age {0}  you've entered must be in the range [1..100]"  ,value);
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( message );
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to why/how this works, so that this answer is useful for future readers as well?